# Json flattening in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Just wondering if its possible to create a column for every key in the json without hardcoding the path when flattening JSON arrays to tables? I have searched up online and in the snowflake community but could not find anything similar. Thanks.

Comment: Not without dynamic SQL (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270341/is-it-possible-to-generate-dynamic-sql-to-return-rows-with-various-columns-in-sn/59273530#59273530)

Comment: thanks @waldente !